# How to deploy war file to tomcat using command prompt?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, command, war

I have created a war file and put into `tomcat/webapps`. How to deploy a war file to tomcat using command prompt?

Answer (score 35):

The earlier answers on this page are correct that you can copy/move the WAR file into place and restart tomcat, but  they omit to mention something: you must remove the previously exploded assets (from the previously deployed WAR file) if any are present.

```bash
# My tomcat webapps are found at /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps
# The application I wish to deploy is the main (ROOT) application
webapps_dir=/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps
# Remove existing assets (if any)
rm -rf $webapps_dir/ROOT
# Copy WAR file into place
cp example_dir/ROOT.war $webapps_dir
# Restart tomcat
service tomcat6 restart
```

Modify the following for your own system:

- Path of your compiled WAR file (to be deployed)
- Path of your tomcat webapps files
- How to restart tomcat (i.e. if not installed as a service)

Answer (score 34):

First add a user role in tomcat-users.xml for role manager-script.

Then to undeploy current app you can use

```
wget http://username:password@localhost:portnumber/manager/text/undeploy?path=/appname -O - -q
```

To deploy

```
wget http://username:password@localhost:portnumber/manager/text/deploy?path=/appname&war=file:/warpath -O - -q
```

Comment: I kept getting "-O: command not found" but if I wrapped the url part with "" then I had no issues, so for others I recommend doing that.

Answer (score 8):

You could use **wget** or **curl** to deploy an app from command line.

With wget:

```
wget --http-user=tomcat --http-password=tomcat "http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?war=file:/some/path/SomeWar.war&path=/SomeWar" -O -
```

But in my case with wget I received this error:
"Failed to deploy application at context path ..."

So I solved using curl:

```
curl -v -u user:password -T app.war 'http://tomcathost/manager/text/deploy?path=/my-app-path&update=true'
```

Comment: Does this un-deploy any existing version?

Comment: I needed to specify PUT specifically with `-X PUT`. Other than that it works perfectly.

Comment: the curl command is the nicest as it contains the update clause that removes the need to undeploy first

Answer (score 6):

To do this, we need to place the WAR file inside the Tomcat `CATALINA_HOME/WEBAPPS/` directory. Later, Tomcat will automatically deploy and explode this WAR file.

- Change active directory of command prompt to your WAR file location
- Set `CATALINA_HOME` variable to the path of the Tomcat directory
- Copy the WAR files

Syntax to copy the WAR file from the current directory in the command line:

```
copy <your-war-file-name> %CATALINA_HOME%\<your-appBase-name>
```

Example:

```
cd C:\MY_WAR_FILE_LOCATION
set CATALINA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.42"
copy MYWARFILE.WAR %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps
```

Note: If a WAR file is copied into the webapps directory while Tomcat is running, it will not be recognized. Simply restart Tomcat to begin using the web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the war file using tomcat manager app, http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely

If you want from command prompt, then as I know

- Stop tomcat (catalina.bat stop)
- copy war to webapp
- restart tomcat (catalina.bat run)

Answer (score 0):

As you have already copied the war file to tomcat/webapps, you just need to restart the tomcat to deploy the war file.

**Command prompt:**

```
set tomcatPath=D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50
call "%tomcatPath%"\bin\catalina.bat **stop**
sleep -m 3000 
call "%tomcatPath%"\bin\catalina.bat jpda **start**
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie) you can upload and deploy the war.

```
http --auth user:pass PUT http://<tomcatURL>/manager/text/deploy?path=/ < ROOT.war
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this it works quite well

```
curl --request PUT --upload-file webapp.war --basic --user user:password \
  http://hostname:port/manager/text/deploy?path=/web_path\&update=true
```

it is based on the published tomcat manager API:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Archive_(WAR)_Remotely