# run springboot application by jar do not include appname in url

Tags: java, deployment, jar

Hi i have made a Jar file of my Springboot app , now when i run it with java -jar myapp.jar it run successfully , but it is accessable at 
localhost:8080/

not on 
localhost:8080/myapp

this do not include appname in url ,

can anyone tell me why and how do we change this setting , while deploy with War file it is working fine on localhost:8080/myapp

Comment: deploy it under Tomcat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029707/how-to-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat-using-command-prompt

Comment: Hi i need to delpoy it by JAR not by War

Answer (score 0):

add this to your application.properties in `src\main\resources` folder

```
server.contextPath=/youapp/*
```

also you can change port

```
server.port = 8880
```

Comment: Hi Parviz , now i am able to access it on my contaxt path , but when i tried to load a file resides in resource folder by class loder                                    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("documents/" + id).getFile());   i am unable to access it and got the following error                   java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\rishabh.jain1\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.2.RELEASE\SpringMVCMavenProject\target\SpringMVCMavenProject.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\documents\sample1.pptx